# Can not find api to reset virtual guest's password

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a requirement that resetting the virtual guest's password when the password is forgotten. And I failed to find a suitable method to reset the password. Maybe reloading the os is a way to reset the password, but it is too crude. Is there any api/method to reset the virtual guest's password?

Comment: What operating system are you running? Can you maybe spawn a shell and execute passwd (on linux systems)?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there’s no API method to reset the Virtual Guest’s password.